# Aws lambda getting executed multiple times

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-cli, aws-sdk-js

I have implemented a simple lambda function which gets triggered whenever there is objected created on s3 bucket.
Whenever an object is created on S3 the lambda gets triggered.However , once the lambda is triggered, the lambda keeps executing at a certain interval even if there is upload on S3 bucket.
Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you share some code and/or the command how you created the Lambda function?

Comment: Its a simple aws function which gets triggered on a object created on s3 bucket
I have just kept a logger



var awsIot = require('aws-iot-device-sdk');
var publishCount = 0;
console.log("########################"+publishCount);

 exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
 console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
};

Comment: Please add the function code by editing the question.  Note that if your function writes to the same bucket, you would expect to have an infinite loop.

Comment: My function is not writing to the same bucket

Comment: There is a timeout error
'Task timed out after 300.02 seconds ' due to which the lambda is executing again .

Answer (score 0):

Your function is timing out because you aren't calling the callback or using the context.succeed() method. I believe retry is two with backoff for errors, but with timeout, S3 will keep retrying for a period of time that is not guaranteed but is usually quite long (a day?)